# Where can I find Gwibber problems to fix?

Tags: development, gwibber

I would like to know what issues gwibber users are facing. For example problems as of Dec 16 with the new twitter change over.

Looking for possible bugs and dev. issues.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand the question.

Comment: I don't think this is actually a question. Check launchpad if you want to find out about bugs and feature requests. AskUbuntu is hardly the place for this.

Comment: @armornick - I think the best response would be to answer the qeustion with links to development sites. I'll edit the question so it makes sense.

Comment: I've found that bug tracking @ launchpad for Gwibber to be a little slow. On Dec.16 twitter changed, and there was a massive twitter outage. -- If you experienced issues with Gwibber or Twitter on or after Dec.16 it may be either a twitter issue or a gwibber issue caused by the new twitter.

Answer (score 4):

The best place to find problem for any program in on that project's development pages and on the bug trackers, for example with Gwibber you can find a lot of information about issues on the launchpad bugs page:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/gwibber/

Comment: I've been to https://bugs.launchpad.net/gwibber/ and the bug issues were not as of the new twitter (Dec.16). I'm trying with this question to poll gwibber users, if problems with gwibber started on or after Dec.16 . I'm trying to track down problems, and confirm bugs that seem to have occurred in Gwibber with the change in twitter.

Comment: @Cyborg - The problem is that this website isn't for polls. Consider doing a search and if the bugs or questions don't already exist, then consider there not to be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/gwibber